# handling options of another select element in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I want to achieve something like that, but not sure how can I do that. Inside a ng-repeat I have 2 select list, based on selection value from first select I need to load the content of second select, JSP code is

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in TypeList">
    <select ng-change="handleChange()">
        <option ng-repeat="c in cList" value="{{c.id}}" ng-disabled="!c.enabled" ng-selected="c.id == TypeList[0].id">{{c.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <select ng-model="outMessageType[obj]" ng-options="t.id as t.name for t in outTypes"></select>
</div>
```

I need to send an ajax call in handleChange() method and on success, I need to refresh the second select list but only for this item generated via TypeList.

js code:

```
$scope.handleChange = function(data) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'url',          
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.outTypes = data.types;
    }
}
```

When I tried to do like this, its updating the value of second select list for all items generated by ng-repeat.

Comment: Maybe you can try to pass `outTypes` as a parameter to `handleChange` and push the values to the array. Don't assign the values, because this will create a new reference. Create the array in the `ng-repeat` div with `ng-init="outTypes = []"`

Comment: can u please provide any sample code?

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/w4gL46v4/4/

Answer (score 0):

Check working demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w4gL46v4/2/).

Use `ng-change` to capture the change event and retrieve the options of the second select list. Use Objects to selected nested options and models.

```
angular.module('Joy', [])
    .controller('JoyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.options = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
    $scope.firsts = {};
    $scope.seconds = {};
        $scope.secondOptions = {};
    $scope.loadSecond = function (userId, index) {
        $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=' + userId).then(function (data) {
            $scope.secondOptions[index] = data.data;
        });
    };
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="Joy" ng-controller="JoyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2]">
        <select ng-model="firsts[i]" ng-change="loadSecond(firsts[i], i)">
            <option ng-repeat="opt in options" value="{{$index}}" name="{{$index}}">User {{opt}}</option>
        </select>Selected: {{first}}
       Posts of this user {{secondOptions[i].length}}:
        <select ng-model="seconds[i]">
            <option ng-repeat="opt in secondOptions[i]" value="{{$index}}" name="{{$index}}">{{opt.title}}</option>
        </select> <hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry if my question was not clear. Actually I need to generate these select boxes multiple times using ng-repeat, see js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w4gL46v4/1/